# How can we increase the height of a Quick Action?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How to increase the height of the Lightning component invoked through quick action in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height of standard quick action Modal using simple configuration provide by salesforce.

1) Go to quick action setup in object.
2) Edit quick action you're using and set height