# footer buttons distorting in case of error on dropdown- Aura component

Tags: aura, quickaction

I have an aura component quick action with a footer with 2 buttons.
Whenever there is any error appearing on 'Status' field, the footer is aligning downwards automatically.

Can you please help me to stop this behaviour and make the footer fixed ?

Attached is the distorted picture.

[image]

Please help me out.
I've already tried all the possible options found, but this footer is not getting fixed.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: @AntonKutishevsky

<footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning:button variant="brand"
                                      label="Cancel"
                                      title="Cancel"
                                      onclick="{!c.handleExit}"/>
                    <lightning:button variant="brand"
                                      label="Submit"
                                      title="Submit"
                                      onclick="{!c.concernModalSave}" />
</footer>

Comment: Hi Team,

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The buttons are fine. But, if you make a quick action and use a lightning component, you must set the height of the quick action window in pixels. This height is fixed. If you receive an error in the component it creates the element with error text and the content gets too big and pushes the buttons to the bottom.

You can try to [increase](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/304492/how-can-we-increase-the-height-of-a-quick-action) the quick action height in the settings. Also, it should be scrollable inside the popup, so your buttons should be visible in some conditions.

Otherwise, you need to hack it with the custom CSS I guess.